# Unable to start keystone service on Docker container

Tags: keystone

I have configured openstack keystone in a docker container but am not able to start the keystone service.
Am getting the below error.

```
root@6cb02ecb9c47:/etc/init.d# service keystone restart keystone:
unrecognized service
```

Can anybody please help me in case if did any mistake in the configuration or do i have to take any special steps to configure keystone in a container.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use the service command within a container. As I understand it docker container does not have a systemd daemon. So you will have to explicitly start your process within the contianer.

eg, instead of "service keystone restart", directly call
"exec /usr/bin/keystone"